# File upload is not working

Tags: files

We are using the file upload field in a custom drupal form, it was working for one (1) year but now it's not. It is working for administrators but not for anonymous users.

I am using the following code.

```
$allowed_exts = array('jpg jpeg gif png txt doc xls xlsx pdf ppt pptx pps odt ods odp docx zip rar');

      $form['file1'] = array(
        '#title' => 'Attachments',
        '#description' => t('Allowed Files - jpg jpeg gif png txt doc xls xlsx pdf ppt pptx pps odt ods odp docx zip rar'),
        '#attributes' => array('id' =>'file_attachment'),
        '#type' => 'managed_file',          
        '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => $allowed_exts,)
      );
```

[image]

Comment: what is the log telling you ? how big was the uploaded file ??

Comment: I am trying the files in file upload field ( png,jpg,txt,xls) which are less than 1 mb, but can't upload

Comment: please provide a log message (from watchdog or apache log)

Answer (score 1):

try to set the location

```
'#upload_location' => 'public://',
```

Comment: I tried '#upload_location' => 'public://', but issue is not solved , the issue is coming only for anonymous user

Comment: please provide a log message (from watchdog or apache log)